# How to calculate the set

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $A = \{ e^{3+i\theta} | \theta \in \Bbb{R} \}$ and $\{ f(x)=x^3  \}$

How can I calculate the set $f(A) = \{ f(x) | x \in A\}$?

Is it $f(A) = \{ e^{9+3i\theta} |    e^{3+i\theta} \in A \}$

Thank you.

Comment: Is $f$ really a constant function?  If so, this is easy....

Comment: What do you mean by $\{f(x)=e^3\}$? Do you mean $f(x)=e^x$?

Comment: typo, i have changed it

Comment: Use \{ \} for brackets. Ie: $\{ \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $f (A)$ is:

$\{f (a)|a\in A\} $.

As $A=\{e^{3+i\theta}|\theta\in \Bbb R\} $ so the elements of $A $ are all in the form $e^{3+i\theta} $ for some real $\theta $.

So $f (A)= \{f (a)|a\in A\}=\{f (e^{3+i\theta})|\theta\in\Bbb R\} =\{e^{3 (3+i\theta)}|\theta\in \Bbb R\} $

Answer (score 1):

The set $A$ is going to be the circle centered about the origin in $\mathbb C$ with radius $r=e^3$. The function $f$ will cube the radius of $A$, and triple $\theta$ for every point in $A$.
So $f(A)=\{e^9e^{3i\theta}: \theta \in \mathbb{R}\}=e^6A$.

Also writing $\theta \in \mathbb R$ is a bit redundant as writing $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ would give the same sets.